# linux bridge cannot send packets, TX packets counter equals 0

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I have setup a bridge according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

my /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth3
allow-hotplug eth3
iface eth3 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
  bridge_ports eth1 eth0
  post-up ifconfig eth0 promisc mtu 9000 && ifconfig eth1 promisc mtu 9000
```

but the statistics show that the bridge doesn't send anything

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:00:83:f4:bc:3b  
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
RX packets:4616 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:628357 (628.3 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I've checked the interfaces state; both are at forwarding state; I set both of them to promiscuous mode and enlarged their MTU (I'm interested in packets above the default MTU).

Answer (score 1):

The `br0` interface is just the "internal" interface in addition to the bridge ports. If you didn't use this IF to send packets, nothing will show up, but the bridge is still forwarding packets between ports.

What are the statistics on the ports (eth1 eth0) themselves?

(And why do you set them into promiscous mode?)

**Edit**

A bridge acts on level 2 OSI, just like a network switch: Conceptually, it forwards all packets it receives on one port to all other ports, including to and from the internally facing port that is the bridge network interface. But just like a real ethernet interface connected to a LAN segment, the network interface counters will only activate for packets addressed to the internal interface (or sent from it).

As an optimization, it keeps a list of MAC addresses seen on ports, and if it recognizes a destination MAC address, it only forwards to this port.

It doesn't change anything in the packet, no MAC addresses or anything else, unless you use `eftables` to do funny things. You can use `tcpdump -e -i eth0` etc. on the ports to verify that yourself.

On old HOWTOs you can find the remark that you must put the port interfaces into promiscious mode, but that hasn't been necessary for a long time. (Just try it out).

Comment: I set it to avoid issues of data filtering, after I get it stable I might remove it. Does the bridge changes MAC addresses or forwards them as it ?